# Expected value of series of uniformly converges random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ a series of i.i.d. variables with 
$X_i \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$.
Let $N=\inf\{n\mid \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\geq1\}$
Prove that $E(N)=e$.

I don't really have a clue how to even start proving that. Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to describe the question as it appears there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for the steps of a possible procedure:

1. Show that $$P(N>t) = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^t x_i<1\right)$$
2. Compute the above probability by geometric considerations (volume of a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume))
3. Use the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formulas_for_special_cases) that for a non-negative valued variable $Y$, $E(Y)=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{ P(Y\ge t)}$